# Restrict possible options of class attributes values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to limit possible options to be chosen when instantiating class objects? Let's say we have a class like below and we'd like to restrict `value` values only to be predefined as in the `valueOptions` list. My implementation attempt is as below. Is there more Pythonic way to achieve the same result?

```py
class TestClass:
    valueOptions = ['A value', 'The value', 'Another value']
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val not in self.valueOptions:
            raise ValueError('Value not in available options.')
        self._value = val
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Value: {self.value}'

v1 = TestClass('A value')  # line 20
v2 = TestClass('Value')  # line 21
```

After run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in __init__
File "<string>", line 14, in value
ValueError: Value not in available options.
```

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do this, your method looks fine.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not very "pythonic", because it's not very duck-typing compatible (the pythonic way of doing this would be to check if the passed value can be acted upon or with as an authorized value). It doesn't mean it's wrong, it's just that it means there probably won't be a very pythonic way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) has support for validating values.

Comment: As long as `valueOptions` is a short list, you might consider defining an `Enum` and not requiring/expecting users to provide one of a small number of exact `str` values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use Enum instead of str if you need a limited values

The core issue is that you (implicitly; your code isn't typed) define `value` as being a string type. But you don't need a string: you need a limited list of possible values. String is not the right variable type to code that.

The [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module allows you to define a enumeration type (class) with a restricted number of options / values.

This actually also solves another issue: the values in your example are hard coded, creating "magic numbers" (or in this case: "magic strings") in your code. Your code will eventually lead to scattered instances of 'A value', 'The value' and 'Another value' in lots of different places. If you (at some future point) decide to replace 'The value' to 'The best value', you have a code maintenance problem...

Here is a code example using enums (and type hints):

```python
from enum import Enum

class ValueOptions(Enum):
	A_VALUE = 'A value',
	THE_VALUE = 'The value',
	ANOTHER_VALUE = 'Another value'

class TestClass:    
    def __init__(self, value: ValueOptions) -> None:
        self.value = value


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Value: {self.value.name}'

v1 = TestClass(ValueOptions.A_VALUE)
print(v1)

v2 = TestClass(ValueOptions.ILLEGAL_VALUE)
print(v2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNaoQwED5vnmJuGtgKu70JLYQibUF2oVivQbojBnQiSRRK6bPbxLXVFjqHZCbz/ZH@3TWabqepNroDpKED1fXaOMh8z9hbW1kLZdUOeO6d0mTjsOAp2wlZivw1gzuIBIwBEe3ZrnjK1veiwXUjTme/fNmwSLsGzYL49irQuofQpeCLheOCNUipSDkpY4ttvb9y0l/BONzcw0kTpjMpVMAmM9T7zTdjG0XrzCI4c/24Ug26wRDUUXl1@li1Eqo6/PSBx4OX/ckbb8Mky@9w1htFLh4P3OOP/@Of8zx7FPkf1pFP0xc)

This leads to valid code for v1, and to an error for v2:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 19, in <module>
    v2 = TestClass(ValueOptions.ILLEGAL_VALUE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/enum.py", line 349, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: ILLEGAL_VALUE
```

This error will not only show at runtime, but (even better!) when writing your code. Any Python code checker (such as `mypy`) will detect that I used an illegal attribute:

```python
❯ mypy ./enum_test.py
enum_test.py:21: error: "Type[ValueOptions]" has no attribute "ILLEGAL_VALUE"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Best of all: this code is a bit shorter than your version! ;-)